# Ecto - querying a table based on an association

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have the following tables:

```
schema "project_users" do
  belongs_to(:user, MyApp.User)
end
```

and

```
schema "users" do
  field(:search_vector, :tsvector)
end
```

I want to query `project_users` based on the `search_vector` result after querying `users` with which is has a `belongs_to` relationship.

I have the following query for `users`. I wonder how I can relate it to `project_users`:

```
def query_all_users(params \\ %{}, preload \\ []) do
  query = from(u in User, preload: ^preload)

  query_by(query, params)
end

defp query_by(query, %{"keyword" => keyword} = params) do
  query = from(q in query, where: fragment("search_vector @@ plainto_tsquery(?)", ^keyword))

  query_by(query, Map.delete(params, "keyword"))
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend making a query that does the join and then filters as so:

```
defmodule ProjectUser do
  use Ecto.Schema

  import Ecto.Query

  schema "project_users" do
    belongs_to :user, User
  end

  @spec by_search_vector(Ecto.Queryable.t, String.t) :: Ecto.Query.t
  by_search_vector(query, search_vector) do
    from pu in query,
      join: u in assoc(pu, :user),
      where: fragment("? @@ plainto_tsquery(?)", u.search_vector, ^search_vector)
  end
end
```

This should easily scope project users down.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you need `has_one`/`has_many` relation `users` to `project_users`.
Update schema `users`:

```
schema "users" do
  field(:search_vector, :tsvector)

  has_one :project_user, ProjectUser  # <---
end
```

and use `preload` function:

```
query |> preload(:project_user)
```